# How to call external groovy script from jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am going through a jenkins pipeline someone else did for my organization. I saw inside that jenkins pipeline it has called to a external groovy script but I have no idea about that process.
This is how it has been called.

```
sh "groovy -cp /apps/scripts /apps/scripts/BuildReport.groovy ${env.BUILD_URL} ${env.BUILD_ID}"
```

I know `${env.BUILD_URL} ${env.BUILD_ID}`  are the arguments that has been passed to the groovy script. But what is the meaning of `groovy -cp` ?

and why `/apps/scripts` has mentioned two times?

can someone clear please..? Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sh` command is using the Groovy installation of your Jenkins Agent. `-cp` argument specifies the `classpath`, this is where your additional dependencies will reside. For example, if `BuildReport.groovy` requires additional dependencies you can point to a directory where the additional dependencies are located. The following is from the groovy man pages.

```
-cp, -classpath, --classpath=<path>
                             Specify where to find the class files - must be
                               first argument
```

Having said that, in your case, if you don't have any dependent Classes, specifying the classpath would be redundant.